# Convert total time into minutes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, time, converters

I am developing a C#(WinForm) application with the goal of recording the service time of a task, and would like the help of you to solve this case.
I need to register two different times, in two different variables (Both have to be current computer schedules), because I will have a start and end time. So I need to calculate this time between the schedules and turn the result into minutes and display it in a TextBox.
I also need to have a total value in minutes and convert this value to time in "hours: minutes".

The code I have is the one below. If anyone can help me, thank you!

```
private void GetHoras()
{
  DateTime total = DateTime.Now;

  string totalTime;
  totalTime = total.ToShortTimeString();
  txtTempo.Text = totalTime;
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried? You posted some code, but it only includes one distinct `DateTime` value, and no code that attempts to calculate the difference (that, or a description of *what* is stumping you or research you've done to address your issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Substract function:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2).AddMinutes(-25);
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan interval = date2.Subtract(date1);

int hoursDiff = interval.Hours;
int minutesDiff = interval.Minutes;
double minutesTotal = interval.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: Or you just write `TimeSpan interval = date2 - date1;`.

Comment: Hello,
I'm sorry for the delay in answering, but that's what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is the [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) struct.

If you subtract one DateTime from another, you'll get a TimeSpan result automatically.

It has members that can give you total minutes or seconds or hours, etc., or the individual parts.

Comment: To address the second part of the question - here is a link to formatting TimeSpan values : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: Hello,
Sorry for the delay in answering. I did not know of the existence of this TimeSpan, but I already researched and found it very practical and interesting for the applications, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
double totalMins = dateTime1.Subtract(dateTime2).TotalMinutes
```

Works for Me with a double value of total minutes as result.